# Rails blocked host: custom error page in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So Rails 6 guards against DNS rebinding attacks and presents a lovely "Blocked host: xxx" page.

My app runs on Heroku, so I get this page if I enter the *.herokuapp.com subdomain.

On the plus side, it's blocked, which is what I want.
On the down side, it shows a standard error page, and I'd rather redirect to the app domain, or show a custom page.

Is there any way to change this behavior in production?

Comment: I have the same issue with a Rails app on Google's Cloud Run. Can't find a way to redirect / customize this page at all.